# Probability to get tails first for one who for the one who tosses the coin first

Tags: probability

Two people play a game, taking turns tossing a coin. The winner is the one who gets tails first. What is the probability of winning in the first toss? I think that its $\frac{1}{2}$ but my textbook says I'm wrong. What is a correct answer and why?

Comment: Probably, a probability distribution is what they(textbooks) may be talking of, aren't they ?

Comment: If yes, then check Bernouli's probability distribution, poisson distribution etc. in Wikipedia or elsewhere.

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham ok, but what is the answer? there is no answers in textbook, a guy who checked wrote that its wrong. its not textbook, but workbook)

Comment: The chance for player $1$ to win is much larger than $\frac{1}{2}$ and probably, this is meant and not the probability that the first toss decides the game.

Comment: Ok, @manabou11, it could be even be a workbook. I am a teen and I am not adept enough to answer your question, but good and kind enough to provide you with hints.

Comment: Yes, you're right, @Peter, it's just that the success rate maybe high, but that doesn't necessarily mean it will be victory for player 1 at first toss. Well done !

Comment: If I guessed right, the correct answer would be $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: If the question is "What is the probability of winning" instead of  "What is the probability of winning in the first toss", then I think @Peter's answwer is right. It is just the sum of the geometric series $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 4 ^{1}} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 4 ^{2}} + .....$. So the answer is just $$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{3} $$

Comment: @LearningMathematics An elegant method is to solve $$p=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-p)$$ but your approach is fine as well.

Comment: @Peter that's true too.

Comment: Also, although I didn't check, this question must be asked somewhere on MSE already.

Comment: Would not be surprising, this is a standard exercise in probability theory.

Answer (score 1):

- $p$ = Probability first player wins. Then

$$p = \frac 12 + \frac12\times \frac 12 \times p \quad \Rightarrow \quad p = \frac 23.$$

- Probability that $k$ or more rounds are needed: $(\frac{1}{4})^{k-1}$. Therefore number of rounds is $\mbox{Geom}(\frac{3}{4})$.
- Conditioned on reaching $k$-th round, probability player $1$ wins on that round is $\frac 12$ and player 2 wins on that round is $\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 14$.
- Therefore, probability player $1$ wins in $k$-th round is
  $\frac 12(\frac{1}{4})^{k-1}$ and player $2$ wins in $k$-th round is half of that $(\frac{1}{4})^{k}$.

**Want game to be fair?**

- Give the players coins with probability $c_1<\frac 12$ and $c_2$ of Tails. Probability player $1$ wins each round is $c_1$ and probability player $2$ wins that round is $(1-c_1)\times c_2$. So game is fair if and only if

$$c_2 = \frac{c_1}{1-c_1}.$$

- If we want to use only one coin, change to: player $1$ wins if lands Tails and player $2$ wins if lands Heads, that is we take $c_2=1-c_2$. With this our condition becomes $(1-c_1) = \frac{c_1}{1-c_1}$, or
  $$ c_1 = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 0.382$$

Comment: thanks, but i didn't get this part $$p = \frac 12 + \frac12\times \frac 12 \times p \quad \Rightarrow \quad p = \frac 23.$$ at all. why so? why  $p = \frac 12 + \frac12\times \frac 12 \times p$ ?

Comment: Because 1/2 is the probability that we win straight away. However if we don't we should be lucky for the opponent not to win this with his first toss, so we only continue with the probability of $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}$. But if we got to this point it looks to us as if we are just starting: we toss first and the coin is the same hence the probability of winning in this case is the same as in the actual problem